# Fetch Youtube info using User Email

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm new on Youtube-api but reading a lot of tutorials and posts i was reaching my goal but now i'm stuck. I hope someone could help me.

I can get the username profile image using json, file_get_contents and the following Youtube-Api link:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/".$username."?fields=media:thumbnail&format=5
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to find "Youtube Username" or "Youtube Display Name" using the account email, eg:

My Youtube email is email@gmail.com, it's possible do find my Youtube Username using only this email ? (Actually i'll use visitors emails to see if they have an Youtube account and fetch their Username or Display Name).

Is this possible ? Can i do this using plain links (Without Authentication Codes or Tokens) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Each YouTube channel is linked to either a corresponding Google Account or a Google+ Page, but there is no way to take an arbitrary email address and translate that into a YouTube channel. And in the case where a channel is linked to a Google+ Page, there isn't actually going to be a real underlying email address.